How would I have a thread wait on a lambda?
This is my first time messing with threads. The project takes user input with a lambda, so I need to wait until that lambda gets valid data to resume the thread. From my research I haven't found a good way to do that other than while (var == null) {} which doesn't seem ideal.
An example that hopefully shows what I want to do is:
(I need to set a variable in a lambda that depends on user input, so it won't be run right away, and I need the thread to wait until the variable is set)
public class MRE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        InputHandler[] handler = new InputHandler[1];
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Object wait = new Object();
            boolean[] matches = new boolean[1];
            synchronized (wait) {
                handler[0] = (message) -> {
                    matches[0] = message.equals("true");
                    wait.notify();
                };
                try {
                    wait.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            //the thread needs the boolean to be set for whatever it does next
        });
        thread.start();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            handler[0].handleMessage(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }

    interface InputHandler {
        void handleMessage(String message);
    }
}


The user-interface (a console in your case) should be handled in a single-thread, not split across multiple threads. Usually that single thread will be the main thread, the thread initially running your app. Use additional threads for tasks not involving the user-interface directly.

FYI, in modern Java we rarely address the Thread class directly. The Executors framework was added to Java 5+ to relieve us Java programmers of the chore of juggling threads. Learn about ExecutorService.

@SolomonSlow the main thread should call wait.notify() through the lambda.

You will get an IllegalMonitorStateException when the lambda is called because wait.notify() outside of a synchronized block. Even though the lambda is defined inside a synchronized block, it's called outside of it.

@BasilBourque I can't really handle it on the main thread because this program handles input from multiple users on that thread, so it can't hang until one specific one sends a message

@RobSpoor I know, that's the problem I'm trying to solve.

D'Oh! I didn't read the code carefully enough. I have deleted my previous comments.

For "your first time messing with threads," I wouldn't touch the Thread class itself.  I also wouldn't touch it for your 1000th time messing with threads.

I got an answer from a java discord, what I need here is a CountDownLatch.
Here's how it would work in my code:
public class MRE {
    InputHandler handler = (message) -> {};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            boolean[] matches = new boolean[1];
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            setHandler((message) -> {
                matches[0] = message.equals("true");
                latch.countDown();
                setHandler((message) -> {});
            });
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            handler.handleMessage(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }

    private void setHandler(InputHandler newHandler) {
        handler = newHandler;
    }

    interface InputHandler {
        void handleMessage(String message);
    }
}


This code is very strange.  You are setting hander[0] inside of the thread but calling it in the main thread which introduces a race condition.  You could easily get a NPE on the handleMessage(...) call if the scanner finishes before the thread starts.  What's the point of allocating an array of 1 InputHandlers anyway?    I would allocate the latch and the InputHandler outside of the thread and then just call the latch.await() in the thread.

Yeah let me fix a lot of that stuff quickly

Apart from the IllegalMonitorStateException waiting to happen because you call wait.notify() outside of a synchronized block, you now call wait.notify() no matter what the outcome of the check is.
The following will only allow the thread to continue once you have a match:
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Object wait = new Object();
            synchronized (wait) {
                handler[0] = (message) -> {
                    synchronized (wait) {
                        if (message.equals("true")) {
                            wait.notify();
                        }
                    }
                };
                try {
                    wait.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            //the thread needs the boolean to be set for whatever it does next
        });

wait.notify() will only be called when the condition is true.

That's not what I want, I just want to set the boolean when any message happens and then resume the thread. The problem is when calling wait.notify() I get that exception, and don't know how to fix it.

The IllegalMonitorStateException is fixed by the synchronized block inside the lambda. I tried the above and the thread only ended after I submitted true. Without the if statement the wait.wait() will finish after the first time the lambda is called, no matter what the input is.

I see that I misinterpreted the "must be set" part. It must be set to either true or false, then the if-statement is indeed not necessary. I interpreted it as "it must be set to true`.
